# Detect Shift + Enter on physical keyboard in Android from Java

Tags: java, android, keyboard, chromebook

In preparing my Android App for Chromebooks use with physical keyboards I want to distinguish in an EditText between receiving an `"Enter" (keyEvent 66)` and `"Shift+Enter" (also keyEvent 66 apparently)` from a physical keyboard. 
I have tried a number of different solutions, such as

- `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` in the activity. The `event.getModifiers()` however always return 0, as do `event.getMetaState(). keyEvent.isShiftPressed()` always returns false.
- `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent)` in the activity with the same result. `keyEvent.isShiftPressed()` always returns false as well.

I have not found a way, whether using `onKeyUp()`, `onKeyPreIme()`, `editText.setOnKeyListener(...)`, or with a `editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {...})`.
I have not had any problems acquiring the `Enter event`, however a `Shift+Enter` is in all the ways I have tried indistinguishable from the `Enter event`.
So my question is this: **has any Android Dev found a way to properly capture the `Shift+Enter` event from a physical keyboard?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem and I fixed it by detecting "Shift" down and "Shift" up events, and define a boolean that store the state.
this is my code, hope help you.

```
final boolean[] isPressed = {false};
    inputEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                if (isPressed[0]) {

                   // Shift + Enter pressed

                    return false;
                } else {

                  // Enter pressed                  

                    return true;
                }
            }

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT)) {
                isPressed[0] = true;
                return false;
            }

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT)) {
                isPressed[0] = false;
                return false;
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this solution seems to be the only real possibility, I haven't found anything better yet :/